# control carousel image height fro different size of screens

Tags: css, carousel, onsen-ui

i work with ons carousel of onsen ui framework. On carousel i have 3 images with 640x426 dimensions. I would like to see the photos on carousel on 100 % of the size independent of the device screen size. My code is :

```
<ons-carousel   style="height:230px;" swipeable  overscrollable auto-scroll auto-refresh  auto-scroll-ratio="0.2" var="carousel">
         <ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="Diamoni_image in DiamoniImagesArray | startFrom : 1" >
            <img src="{{Diamoni_image.path}}">
            </ons-carousel-item>
            <ons-button style="margin-top:25%;  background-color: rgba(25, 142, 187, 0.5); float:right" ng-click="carousel.next()">
               <ons-icon icon="fa-arrow-right"></ons-icon>
            </ons-button>
            <ons-button style="margin-top:25%;  background-color: rgba(25, 142, 187, 0.5); float:left" ng-click="carousel.prev()">
                <ons-icon icon="fa-arrow-left"></ons-icon>
            </ons-button>
        </ons-carousel>
```

i set the height at 230px but in some devices with big screen the picture is not all visible .How to control this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You used fix height, So that in big screens it looks small. For that you need to use fix height only in small devices.See the below code, Hope it works for you.

---

```
<ons-carousel class="ons" swipeable  overscrollable auto-scroll auto-refresh  auto-scroll-ratio="0.2" var="carousel">
<ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="Diamoni_image in DiamoniImagesArray | startFrom : 1" >
<img src="{{Diamoni_image.path}}">
</ons-carousel-item>
<ons-button style="margin-top:25%;  background-color: rgba(25, 142, 187, 0.5); float:right" ng-click="carousel.next()">
<ons-icon icon="fa-arrow-right"></ons-icon>
</ons-button>
<ons-button style="margin-top:25%;  background-color: rgba(25, 142, 187, 0.5); float:left" ng-click="carousel.prev()">
<ons-icon icon="fa-arrow-left"></ons-icon>
</ons-button>
</ons-carousel>
```

---

**css**

```
@media (max-width: 768px){ 
    .ons{
        height:230px;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This not resolved ,the image stop to be visible at 25% of screen where is the ons-button.